# Proving irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I was given the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 -8$. I have successfully proved it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Does this imply it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: Every real cubic equation has a real root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ irreducible does not imply $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ irreducible. For instance $f(x)=x^2-2$. This has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$, but roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since your polynomial has degree 3 it follows easyly from the intermediate value theorem, that is has at least one root.

Answer (score 2):

It must be reducible over $\mathbb R $. It is a 3rd degree polynomial and so must have a real root.

Comment: in this case the only real root is about 1.3553?

Comment: Zero is not its root, but some other real number is. It is just for large $x $ $f (x) $ is positive, and for "small" $x $ (i.e. negative $x$ with large $|x|$) $f (x) $ is negative - so at some point in between,  being continuous, $f (x) $ must be $0$.

Comment: @undergrad Yes, 1.3553 looks abot right; anyway, this means $f (x)=(x-1.3553\ldots)(x^2+ax+b) $ for some $a $ and $b $, thus the polynomial is reducible.

Answer (score 2):

Real $3$. degree polynomial is always reducible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

used fundadamental theorem of algebra.....every odd degree polynomial has atleast one root in $\mathbb{R}$